# How to get OUT parameter as collection from Oracle stored function with PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I've got Oracle stored function from the owner (I didn't write the function), which looks like this

```
FUNCTION get_customer_data
(
    iref_no_list      IN  t_param_tab,
    ocust_data_list   OUT NOCOPY t_customer_data_tab,
    oerrmsg           OUT VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_PARAM_TAB force IS TABLE OF t_param_obj;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_PARAM_OBJ FORCE AS OBJECT 
(
    par_name   VARCHAR2(30),  /*Parameter name*/
    par_value  VARCHAR2(50),  /*Parameter value*/

    MEMBER FUNCTION to_string RETURN VARCHAR2
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_CUSTOMER_DATA_TAB IS TABLE OF t_customer_data_obj;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_CUSTOMER_DATA_OBJ FORCE AS OBJECT
(
  full_name         VARCHAR2(360 CHAR),
  first_name        VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  last_name         VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  identity_number   VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  email             VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
  phone_number      VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),

  MEMBER FUNCTION to_string RETURN VARCHAR2
);
```

and the PHP code looks like this

```
$connection = oci_connect("username", "password", "connect string");

$sql = "DECLARE
           iref_no_list    t_param_tab := t_param_tab(t_param_obj('CA_REF_NO', '1111111111'));
        BEGIN
           :rc := get_customer_data(iref_no_list    => iref_no_list,
                                    ocust_data_list => :output,
                                    oerrmsg         => :message);
        END;";

$stmt = oci_parse($connection, $sql);

$output = oci_new_collection($connection, "T_CUSTOMER_DATA_TAB");

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":output", $output, -1, OCI_B_NTY);

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":message", $errorMessage, 4000, SQLT_CHR);

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":rc", $resultNumber);

oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

The problem is, I just can't get that collection printed out. It returns message and return value, but collection returns only *collection => oci8 collection resource*.

I tried

```
$count = $output->size();
for ($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++) {
   $outputArray[] = $output->getElem($i);
}
```

but it just returns *false*.

Do you know any solution for this?
Thank you.

Comment: The general solution is to add extra statements to your anonymous PL/SQL to map data into types that can be bound from PHP. There might be some techniques in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf) that help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I can't really change types or add some statements otherwise the function won't work. I read the book, but haven't find any particular solutions.

Comment: Check p209 "Using OCI8 Collection Functions" of that pdf

Comment: I see, the problem is, I can't edit the function. It's saved on the server and I don't have access to it.

Comment: You don't have to edit the function: you can put the extra logic in the DECLARE/BEGIN/END block wrapper that you already call.